# View transitions api does not fade when using all: unset

Tags: css, view-transitions-api

When using the transitions API in a vue project for example:

```
document.startViewTransition(() => {
  router.push({name: 'Index'})
});
```

This works correctly and every page transitions with a fade effect.

However, I have used a CSS reset like so:

```
*:where(:not(iframe, canvas, img, svg, video):not(svg *, symbol *)) {
  all: unset;
  display: revert;
}
```

The `all: unset` causes the view transitions to only work on elements where I specify a name, meaning the default fade no longer works.

So my question is, how do I reinstate the default view transition properties?

I have tried various combinations of the new CSS syntax like so:

```
*::view-transition-old(),
*::view-transition-new() {
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
}
```

But nothing has worked so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could exclude the view transition from your reset.

```css
*:where(:not(iframe, canvas, img, svg, video, ::view-transition):not(svg *, symbol *)) {
  all: unset;
  display: revert;
}
```